# horizontalpodautoscaler min and max replica are 1 creates 2 pods

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to run horizontalpodautoscaler resource defining mix and max replica as 1.
somehow once it started to run 2 instances of the pod are running in the same time then 1 pod is terminated.
End state I have 1 pod running.

Is this the normal behaviour of HPA resource that somehow its created replicaset with 2 pods even the maximum is one

Thanks

Comment: Where is your cluster deployed? I have the same issue in GKE.

Comment: in openshift cluster which is running on regular vm not GKE

Answer (score 0):

Generally it will not happen. The only reason it could occur if hpa target  metric target is very low and starting the application is crossing the target CPU threshold causing scaling of pods.

You can check the HPA status, `events section` can explain the reason for scaling.

HPA status: ***kubectl describe HPA_NAME***

Check below example for reference

```
    Metrics:                                               ( current / target )
  resource cpu on pods  (as a percentage of request):  40% (406m) / 50%
Min replicas:                                          10
Max replicas:                                          100
Conditions:
  Type            Status  Reason              Message
  ----            ------  ------              -------
  AbleToScale     True    ReadyForNewScale    the last scale time was sufficiently old as to warrant a new scale
  ScalingActive   True    ValidMetricFound    the HPA was able to succesfully calculate a replica count from cpu resource utilization (percentage of request)
  ScalingLimited  False   DesiredWithinRange  the desired replica count is within the acceptible range
Events:
  Type    Reason             Age                   From                       Message
  ----    ------             ----                  ----                       -------
  Normal  SuccessfulRescale  35m (x1216 over 12d)  horizontal-pod-autoscaler  New size: 10; reason: All metrics below target
```

Comment: I noticed that somehow 2 replica set are created then 2 pods are created but then HPA validate that the current state is 2 and the desired is 1 and kill one of the pods. is this normal even i dont have any issue of CPU

Comment: Check the deployment definition, if replica is set to 2 change it to 1.

```spec:
  replicas: 2```

Comment: its 1 but still 2 pod are created and 2 replica set  and then 1 terminated by HPA

Comment: I shared the deployment spec and status

Comment: That’s not helping out. Are you using deployment or replicaset for example-ms ?

Comment: I am creation a resource of Deployment and then a resource of HPA

Comment: is the order of running the resource is important in my case i am running deployment then hpa

Comment: Please provide your yaml spec for Deployment and HorizontalPodAutoscaler

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check if you defined somewhere "replicas" inside your deployment.yaml.
If you defined it, then the initial number of pods will bee the number you set on the replicas.
After that, HPA will get to work and will kill one of the pods since you defined the max to 1.
For more help, please share your *.yaml files.